# Firefox having multiple identities / sessions mixed up in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, launcher

From what I can tell Firefox in Kubuntu installed via Snap has multiple different sessions depending on how and when it's opened. This means I can login to my Firefox account and still have an app opening another Firefox instance (since it's my default browser) where I'm still logged out.

It seems to open different sessions when:

- I type `firefox` in the application launcher
- an app opens Firefox as the default browser
- after a snap update

I'm using Kubuntu 23.10 but this seems to be an issue for a few versions now, though 23.10 has the most annoying "switches".

Also, there is no Firefox app in the launcher, since it's installed via Snap. As well in `Default Applications` I cannot set the app by default, I have to refer to `/snap/bin/firefox` as a terminal app.

What is the recommended way in Kubuntu to set Firefox the default browser, so no matter how it starts it will be the same session (where I'm logged in)?

Comment: I experienced the same problems with 22.04. There I have two firefox snaps, one in `/snap/bin/firefox` and one in `/snap/firefox/<some version number>/.../bin/firefox`. Unfortunately I don't have a solution. I tried to add an application link to `~.local/share/applications/`. If I do so, it shows up as an application and should be selectable as an application, but I am not sure how this holds up under updates.